# Submit form load results instead of messages

Tags: forms, 8

I am testing out the new Drupal 8 custom modules and currently stuck with the submit form handler to load form submitted results in the same page and my current functions of last submit is this (inside the controller form) :

```
    <?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\resume\Form\ResumeForm.
 */
namespace Drupal\resume\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class ResumeForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'resume_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['candidate_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Candidate Name:'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['candidate_mail'] = array(
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => t('Email ID:'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['candidate_number'] = array (
      '#type' => 'tel',
      '#title' => t('Mobile no'),
    );

    $form['candidate_dob'] = array (
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#title' => t('DOB'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['candidate_gender'] = array (
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => ('Gender'),
      '#options' => array(
        'Female' => t('Female'),
        'male' => t('Male'),
      ),
    );

    $form['candidate_confirmation'] = array (
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => ('Are you above 18 years old?'),
      '#options' => array(
        'Yes' =>t('Yes'),
        'No' =>t('No')
      ),
    );

    $form['candidate_copy'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Send me a copy of the application.'),
    );

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

      if (strlen($form_state->getValue('candidate_number')) < 10) {
        $form_state->setErrorByName('candidate_number', $this->t('Mobile number is too short.'));
      }

    }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

   // drupal_set_message($this->t('@can_name ,Your application is being submitted!', array('@can_name' => $form_state->getValue('candidate_name'))));

    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
      drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }

   }
}
```

I wanted to show results in a table in the same page form where user submit the form, rather than just throwing in messages

thank you

Comment: Above code working fine for me..
Kindly post complete code to check throughly..

Comment: @AAjayKumarReddy updated form

Answer (score 1):

The example of @Ajay was not working for me. 
This one do. Hope this help.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // Your $form fields here ...

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );

    // Render this field bellow the submit button and above return $form.
    if (!empty($formValues = $form_state->getValues())){

      $header = ["Key","Value"];

      $output = [];
      foreach ($formValues as $key => $value) {
        if ($key=='submit'){
          break;
        }
        $output[$key]['key'] = $key;
        $output[$key]['value'] = $value;
      }

      $form['mytable'] = [
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => $output,
        '#empty' => t('No Data'),
      ];
    }

    return $form;
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Soon I'll write a post about other ways to render form's data in a controller or even with a Private Temp Storage

Comment: Thanks for this solution it works like charm, Can you help on how can i get checkbox in $output[$key]['key'] if I try adding html it just loads plain html

Answer (score 0):

After submit check for

```
     if(isset($form_state->getValues())){
        $header = array(
          array('key' => t('Key')),
          array('value' => t('Value')),
        );
        $output = array();
        foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
           $output['key'] = $key;
           $output['value'] = $value;
        }
        $form['mytable'] = array(
          '#type' => 'table',
          '#header' => $header,
          '#rows' => $output,
          '#empty' => t('No Data'),
        )),
     }
```

in buildForm and try like this.

Comment: do I join like $form['asd']['#prefix'] = 'value'; as I need to build table into it thank you

Comment: Updated answer, try this once

Comment: not working, as I checked the form_state are empty once its submitted, it is not returning ot the build form?

Comment: $input = &$form_state->getUserInput();
Once try this, but this will give your table even if validation is there.

Comment: I am processing the input and resubmitting as another variable is it possible to send arguments or value back to the storage? like in submitForm : form_state->get('value1') * form_state->get('value2');